# Was Ellis Island the only immigration inspection station in New York in the 1880's?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, immigration, new-york-city

This question was brought about by the fact that some of my ancestors immigrated from Russia to New York in the 1880's. The source I have for that fact is a citizenship application. Was Ellis Island the only operating immigration inspection station in New York at the time? If not, what other stations were there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. During the 1880s, immigrants entering New York Harbor went through the state-controlled facility at Castle Garden.

Between August 1, 1855 and April 18, 1890, [**Castle Garden**](http://www.castlegarden.org/) was the original immigration station before Ellis Island opened. It handled about 8 million immigrants before the Federal Government took charge of the immigration process. The [CastleGarden.org](http://www.castlegarden.org/searcher.php)  will let you search by name and time period.

While Ellis Island was under construction, **the Barge Office at [the Battery](http://www.thebattery.org/)** was used for processing immigrants.

[**Ellis Island**](http://www.ellisisland.org/) opened in 1892. Between January 1, 1892 and November 1954, over 12 million immigrants entered the US through Ellis Island ([timeline](http://www.ellisisland.org/genealogy/ellis_island_timeline.asp)). You can [search the ships' manifests](http://www.ellisisland.org/genealogy/ellis_island_search_tips_advanced.asp) transcribed from 1892 to 1924.

Answer (score 7):

An earlier facility in New York was called [Castle Garden](http://castlegarden.org/). It processed immigrants from  1855 to 1890. It was replaced by Ellis Island to handle a larger volume of immigrants.

Comment: So Castle Garden was the only operating station in NY at the time?

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify what the previous two answers are saying, if your ancestors came to NYC in the 1880s, they did *not* come through Ellis Island.  They came through Castle Garden.

Answer (score 4):

If your ancestor migrated before 1892, you will want these [New York Passenger List](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/New_York,_Passenger_Lists_%28FamilySearch_Historical_Records%29) records from Family Search which predate the transfer from Castle Garden on Manhattan to Ellis Island.

Be aware that this is old-school genealogy that involves scanning the images for a name, not just typing into a search box!

Comment: Is there something in these lists not included in Ancestry's NY ship manifests from this time period?

Comment: Since both providers say that their data is drawn from the same source (NARA publication M237: *Passenger Lists of Vessels Arriving at New York*, New York, 1820-1897), there may not be significant differences. But since use of FS is free, I would cross-check to look for transcription errors or other variations.

Comment: JustinY, I have created a meta question http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/what-is-the-preferred-style-for-displaying-links You will probably want to express your view.

Comment: Although I don't know about this specific time period, I know from experience and reading that Ancestry has uploaded manifest images out of order and even left out images, usually the first and last pages in a run. I know of one instance where they left out a entire ship's voyage entering San Francisco in 1954. I do not know how careful and inclusive FamilySearch has been uploading their manifest images.